# java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unsupported Service: accessibility android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, material-design

I have ran into a problem with this UnsupportedOperationException. I have recently switched to android studio, so it is quite new for me. I wanted to add the recyclerview into my project, and do stuff with it, but the layout designer throws me this error:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unsupported Service: accessibility
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.android.BridgeContext.getSystemService(BridgeContext.java:465)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.<init>(RecyclerView.java:290)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.<init>(RecyclerView.java:266)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:379)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:99)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallback.loadView(LayoutlibCallback.java:172)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:207)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:132)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:806)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:385)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:401)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:329)
at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:333)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService$5.compute(RenderService.java:674)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService$5.compute(RenderService.java:663)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:932)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.createRenderSession(RenderService.java:663)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.render(RenderService.java:790)
at com.intellij.android.designer.designSurface.AndroidDesignerEditorPanel$6.run(AndroidDesignerEditorPanel.java:480)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:320)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:310)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$2.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:254)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:269)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:227)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:217)
at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:327)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

What should be the problem, I don't honestly know. I've watched tutorials for implementing RecyclerView into the project, but this is what Android Studio gives me back after I use the official Google code.

---

EDIT: It seems it is resolved as the answer I accepted is correct, but I did not tried it on my own.

EDIT: As I accepted the current answer, it is somewhat relevant to my issue, but it's not a full solution. If anyone can or could provide some fix or workaround to this, I'll update the accepted answer as long as its providing such an information, or if the issue was solved by IntelliJ or whoever is the developer. Also thank you Dave for pointing out where it fails, at least we can write a ticket to devs :)

Comment: The layout designer seems to have some issues with views coming from libraries.

Comment: that's perfectly okay, as soon it'll work on some basic level...but how can I get around it? :)

Comment: AFAIK, you'll need to work at the XML level, instead of the drag-and-drop stuff.

Comment: this is also on XML level, not only the designer itself

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue was finally fixed in the API Level 22 SDK Manager and RecyclerView support library. To quote [this comment](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=72117#c28) in the relevant Android issue (which was closed on March 11, 2015), you need to:

> ... update to the latest SDK platform for API 22 via the SDK Manager,
>   and update to the latest recycler view by updating the Support
>   repository via the SDK Manager, and in your build.gradle file to use
>   the latest version (22.0.0)

In addition, at the top of the designer tool, you need to select API Android version 22. If you pick an earlier version, you will continue to see the error, even though you have the latest support library.

Comment: hello, please could you prove this answer, hence I have no android studio installed recently. If your answer is true, then I'll give you the correct answer checkmark :)

Comment: I solved this issue on my own machine following the same steps.

Answer (score 4):

`BridgeContext.getSystemService()` (as of 5.0.0 r1) will throw `UnsupportedOperationException` if the service requested isn't one of the following:

- "layout_inflater"
- "textservices"
- "window"
- "input_method"
- "power"
- "display"

In such cases, the Exception thrown will contain the name of the service that was requested.

It seems that IntelliJ's UI helpers haven't been updated, because `BridgeContext` shouldn't be asking for the "accessibility" service. As the commenters have suggested, stick to the XML layout, rather than the WYSIWYG.

Comment: but I think it's pretty funny that such a platform as Android is, don't have good tools as for example Visual Studio or Xcode are...thanks anyway

Comment: It's not Android's fault, it's IntelliJ (or whoever wrote the WYSIWYG editor used in IntelliJ) that hasn't kept up with the Android specification.

Comment: I'm not saying that Android's fault it is. I just wanted to point out, that google took the IntelliJ base to form the Android Studio...if I were in that position, I'd better assure that on the launch day of my OS is available at least one stable IDE for developers to use which don't make them cry blood and piss lead

Comment: WYSIWYG editors typically lag behind the development of the product they support. That's generally one of the reasons why most people don't like WYSIWYG editors. Understanding the underlying XML is much better for future-proofing projects, even though it takes more effort.

Comment: while true, but that is not an option, when the consumer wants to see the result right at that moment :)

Comment: Isn't that what the emulator is for?

Comment: yes but the out of the box android emulator takes years to build and run, also it's crashing a lot...and I don't have an android device unfortunately

Comment: I like WYSIWYG editors and don't much care what the underlying XML is like. Unfortunately, to get real work done on Android you have to understand the XML. I liken the XML to Java bytecode - since you can rely on Java to generate the correct bytecode, you can move on to higher abstractions (writing your Java). The same is true for WYSIWYG editors - let's leave the low level behind and focus on build apps, not on making sure your tags have matching start and ends and other XML minutia.

Comment: On the assumption that the WYSIWYG editor is made by the same team that write the API that it uses, then yes, your point stands. However, in this particular example, it is not. As a result, this particular WYSIWYG editor will always lag behind product development. Although it seems from the accepted answer that Android dev have decided to re-introduce the support for certain Services, which fixes this issue. Unfortunately though, that isn't a solution that works for older Android devices.

Answer (score 1):

I found this error in latest 1.5.1 studio.
In my case it is fixing by changing API level for previewing.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's the case, the same happended to me with a `GLSurfaceView`-extending class.

I overrode `onDraw(Canvas)` for debugging purpose:

```
@Override protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    this.toString();    // ← wanted a break here
    super.onDraw(canvas);
}
```

As soon as I removed meaningless `this.toString();`, the designer started working.

Answer (score 0):

Jost Change Api level 22 or 23.

[image]