# android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView failed to instantiate

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-support-library

I created an Android application project in eclipse for APIs 15-21.

I imported libraries of appCompat v7, cardView and recyclerView but on adding recyclerView in my XML it gives ***android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView*** failed to instantiate.

I have the latest SDK with updated libraries.

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unsupported Service: accessibility
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.android.BridgeContext.getSystemService(BridgeContext.java:465)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.<init>(RecyclerView.java:290)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.<init>(RecyclerView.java:266)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.ProjectCallback.instantiateClass(ProjectCallback.java:442)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.ProjectCallback.loadView(ProjectCallback.java:194)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:207)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:132)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:806)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:385)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:401)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:329)
at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:332)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.RenderService.createRenderSession(RenderService.java:517)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.renderWithBridge(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1584)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.recomputeLayout(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1309)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart$ReloadListener.reloadLayoutSwt(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1817)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart$ReloadListener.access$0(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1755)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart$ReloadListener$1.run(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1749)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:136)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4147)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3764)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1151)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1032)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:148)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:636)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:579)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:135)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
```

Comment: thanks for sharing your stack trace.

Comment: I also got same problem. How u solved it. Please help me. Thanks in regards.. @Rulogarcillan

Comment: One more solution for the same problem for android studio in corresponding question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26792510/java-lang-unsupportedoperationexception-unsupported-service-accessibility-andr/35969615#35969615

Answer (score 15):

This issue was finally fixed in the API Level 22 SDK Manager and RecyclerView support library. To quote [this comment](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=72117#c28) in the relevant Android issue (which was closed on March 11, 2015), you need to:

> ... update to the latest SDK platform for API 22 via the SDK Manager,
>   and update to the latest recycler view by updating the Support
>   repository via the SDK Manager, and in your build.gradle file to use
>   the latest version (22.0.0)

In addition, at the top of the designer tool, you need to select API Android version 22. If you pick an earlier version, you will continue to see the error, even though you have the latest support library.

Answer (score 5):

Is this a problem on the preview window or at runtime ?

RecyclerView needs a LayoutManager to be rendered.

In you Java code, add the following :

```
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
```

Comment: The problem is in preview window

Comment: The component is simply not designed to be previewed ... We just have to wait for an update of the support library.

You can set the visibility of the recyclerView to gone in the tools xmlns to continue working with the preview.

Comment: It's as if my library was defective, or even my old SDK I have downloaded the latest when I create a brand new application 4.X L preview not 5.0.

I used to download android sdk manager


How change configration visibility?

Comment: I tried `tools:visibility="gone"` in Android Studio but it still throws the same exception. `tools:visibility` itself works (tried that on other views).

Comment: Did they fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add android-support-v7-recyclerview.jar file. It located in *sdk\extras\android\support\v7\recyclerview\libs*

Comment: This answer does not solve the problem.  However just fyi more detail is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24440852/how-to-import-recyclerview-for-android-l-preview

Comment: this is not solutions !