# Support RecyclerView will not render in the Layout Editor on any API below 23

Tags: android, rendering, android-recyclerview

i have recycler view in layout but when i run my project older than 23 api.it not worked and give below exception.how to solved it.recycer view is supported below 23 api or not? what is the other option for that.

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unsupported Service: accessibility
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.android.BridgeContext.getSystemService(BridgeContext.java:447)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.<init>(RecyclerView.java:475)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.<init>(RecyclerView.java:450)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:458)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:170)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:103)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallbackImpl.loadView(LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java:190)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:206)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:131)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:739)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:711)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:742)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:711)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:742)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:711)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:372)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:369)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:326)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:350)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:510)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:498)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:888)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:498)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.access$600(RenderTask.java:72)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$3.call(RenderTask.java:610)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$3.call(RenderTask.java:607)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.runRenderAction(RenderService.java:366)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:607)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:629)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.doRender(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:652)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.access$1700(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:80)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager$7$1.run(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:594)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$2.run(CoreProgressManager.java:152)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:452)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:402)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:137)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager$7.run(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:589)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:320)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:310)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$2.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:254)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:269)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:227)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:217)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
    at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:351)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

complaint_status.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/relvMain"
    android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/frame1">
        <ScrollView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/Scroll"
            android:fillViewport="true">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">
        <!--<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/txt_changesmspin"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:textColor="@color/heading_text" />

        </RelativeLayout>-->


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/cid"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/complaint_id"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/textview_size"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margintop_space"
                    android:hint="@string/cid"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="OR"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:textColor="@color/heading_text" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/date"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/cdate"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="date"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/textview_size"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margintop_space"
                    android:hint="@string/lbl_date"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal">
                <CheckBox
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/not_remember"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/textview_size"
                    android:id="@+id/chknotRem"
                    android:padding="6dp"
                    android:checked="false"
                    android:textColor="@color/textview_all">
                </CheckBox>
            </LinearLayout>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_cstatus"
                android:text="@string/btn_submit"
                android:textColor="@color/btn_text"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="51dp"
                android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
                android:shadowColor="@color/btn_text_shadow"
                android:shadowDx="0"
                android:shadowDy="0"
                android:shadowRadius ="@integer/btn_text_shadowradius"
                android:textSize ="@dimen/btn_text_size"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </FrameLayout>
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/frame2">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/cardComplaintstatus"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

complaintstatus.java

```
public class ComplaintStatus extends BaseActivity{

    Button submitButton;
    FrameLayout frame1,frame2;
    EditText cid,cdate;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    private RecyclerAdapterComplaintStatus mAdapter;
    int year,month,day,selectYear,selectMonth,selectDay;
    static final int TO_DATE_PICKER_ID = 2222;
    CheckBox not_remeber;
    Calendar c;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.complaint_status);

        if (!(Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler() instanceof ExceptionHandler)) {
            Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new ExceptionHandler(this));
        }

        submitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_cstatus);
        frame1 = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frame1);
        frame2 = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frame2);

        cid = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.complaint_id);
        cdate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cdate);

        frame2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        not_remeber = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chknotRem);
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.cardComplaintstatus);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        not_remeber.setChecked(false);

        c = Calendar.getInstance();
        year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        cdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showDialog(TO_DATE_PICKER_ID);
            }
        });

        submitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String c_id= "" ,c_date = "";
                c_id = cid.getText().toString();
                c_date = cdate.getText().toString();

                if(!not_remeber.isChecked()) {
                    if (c_id.length() == 0 && c_date.length() == 0) {
                        toastValidationMessage(ComplaintStatus.this, "Please fill any one from Complaint ID  OR Complaint Date ");
                        cid.requestFocus();
                        return;

                    }else if (!(c_id.length() == 0) && !(c_date.length() == 0)) {
                        toastValidationMessage(ComplaintStatus.this,"Please fill only one from Complaint ID  OR Complaint Date ");
                        cid.requestFocus();
                        return;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    if (c_id.length() > 0 && c_date.length() > 0) {
                        toastValidationMessage(ComplaintStatus.this,"Please Remove the value of Complaint ID AND Complaint Date");
                        cid.requestFocus();
                        return;
                    }else if (c_id.length() > 0 || c_date.length() > 0) {
                        toastValidationMessage(ComplaintStatus.this,"Please Remove the value of Complaint ID OR Complaint Date");
                        cid.requestFocus();
                        return;
                    }
                }
                if(c_date.length() > 0) {
                    validateDate(ComplaintStatus.this, selectMonth, selectYear, selectDay, month, year, day,"validatebothFromToDate");
                    cdate.requestFocus();
                }
                        try {
                            boolean con = isInternetConnected();
                            if (con) {
                                AsyncTaskComplaintStatus atw = new AsyncTaskComplaintStatus(ComplaintStatus.this,c_id,c_date,"COMPLAINTID","COMPLAINTDATE","COMPLAINTTYPE","DESCRIPTION","STATUS");
                                ArrayList<ComplaintStatusGeSe> try1 = atw.execute("GetComplaintStatus").get();

                                if (ResponseString.getStcode().equals("0")) {
                                    frame1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    frame2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                    mAdapter = new RecyclerAdapterComplaintStatus(ComplaintStatus.this, AsyncTaskComplaintStatus.mlistArray);
                                    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(ComplaintStatus.this);
                                    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
                                    mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new SimpleDividerItemDecoration(getResources()));
                                    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                                } else {
                                    toastValidationMessage(ComplaintStatus.this,sMsg);
                                }
                            } else {
                                toastValidationMessage(ComplaintStatus.this,getResources().getString(R.string.checkinternet));
                            }
                        } catch (Exception ie) {
                            Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new ExceptionHandler(ComplaintStatus.this));
                        }
                   }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
            case TO_DATE_PICKER_ID:
                return new DatePickerDialog(this, frompickerListener, year, month,day);
        }
        return null;
    }
    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener frompickerListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        // when dialog box is closed, below method will be called.
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {

            selectYear  = selectedYear;
            selectMonth = selectedMonth;
            selectDay   = selectedDay;
            cdate.setText(new StringBuilder().append(selectDay).append("/").append(selectMonth + 1).append("/").append(selectYear).append(" "));
        }
    };
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_signout:
                logout(ComplaintStatus.this);
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            doExit();
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
    private void doExit() {
        finish();
        Intent intent = new Intent(ComplaintStatus.this,HomePage.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    /*@Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        if ((BaseActivity.pleaseWaitDialog != null) && BaseActivity.pleaseWaitDialog.isShowing()) {
            BaseActivity.pleaseWaitDialog.dismiss();
            BaseActivity.pleaseWaitDialog = null;
        }
    }*/
}
```

Comment: Share your XML and code

Comment: please see my updated question

Comment: check it here 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/29555011/1292203